# What's the meaning in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The day passed quickly

What is the meaning in context? Which one of these options:

- to get over
- exceed
- pronounce
- approve
- to excrete
- to ignore
- to happen
- to go by
- to transfer

Answer (score 1):

*To go by* is the meaning here. And in the vast majority of cases, this is of course not referring to the literal length of the day, but how long it subjectively felt.

The phrase is equivalent to:

> The day [felt like it] went by quickly.